# Как сделать позиционирование контента в карточке одинаково с остальными по горизонтали в bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  max-width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-title">Title</div>
    <div class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, laudantium eveniet placeat eos debitis voluptatum similique laborum hic dolor. Mollitia dolore atque adipisci ex veritatis dicta, possimus minus magni quas!</div>
    <small class="d-block">Subtitle</small>
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Button</button>
  </div>  
    <div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-title">Title</div>
    <div class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, laudantium eveniet placeat eos debitis voluptatum similique laborum hic dolor. Mollitia dolore atque adipisci ex veritatis dicta, possimus minus magni quas!</div>
    <small>Subtitle</small>
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Button</button>
  </div>  
  
    <div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-title">Title</div>
    <div class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, laudantium eveniet placeat eos debitis voluptatum similique laborum hic dolor. Mollitia dolore atque adipisci ex veritatis dicta, possimus minus magni quas! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam nemo laudantium cum laborum delectus temporibus ratione deleniti expedita cumque ducimus praesentium atque necessitatibus, obcaecati amet. Voluptatum omnis ullam natus fuga!</div>
    <small class="d-block">Subtitle</small>
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Button</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Я хотел бы добиться результата на пк версий, где в первых 2-х блоков кнопки с тегом small были внизу как в 3. Т.е независимо от размеров контента нижняя часть была одинаковой у всех по расположению. Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: Так, например: `<button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Button</button>` => `<button class="btn btn-success mt-2 w-100 btn-bottom">Button</button>` и стили `.btn-bottom { position: absolute; bottom: 0;}` или просто удалите у button клас mt-2 и добавьте стиль `margin-top: auto;`

Comment: @InDevX а что с тегом small делать?

Comment: Если во всех блоках сперва small потом button - добавьте `margin-top: auto;` для small, он подвинет button вниз. Или для контента (card-text) добавьте стиль `flex: 1;` и он будет "прижимать" вниз всё что после него